# Book identification in which a girl inserts chloroplasts under her skin

Tags: story-identification, books

In the story I’m thinking of, the girl turns to inserting chloroplasts under her skin in a secretive act, becoming greener. In the book, she seems to struggle emotionally. She eventually becomes a plant and in my memory it is a welcome result for her. The word 'metamorphoses' comes to mind. Like [Ovid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphoses), but more recent.

I read it around the time I read Amélie Nothomb’s *[The Character of Rain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Character_of_Rain)* and wonder if they haven't spliced somewhat in my mind, but am certain that is not the book. The book I read took place in a space colony where the girl's father was busy. Asimov vibes here.

I don't think it was *[Catalyst](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.ca/books/314990/catalyst-by-lydia-kang/9780698191426/excerpt)* by Lydia Kang.

And I don’t think it was *[The Cure for Love and Other Tales of the Biotech Revolution](http://www.philsp.com/stableford/collections/cure_for_love.htm)* by Brian M. Stableford.

… the search continues so if any book or text comes to mind I would appreciate you sharing :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: From tvtropes: In Top Secret (aka The Strange Thing that Happened to Allen Brewster), a kid performs a science experiment on himself that changes him plant person, to the point that he begins to photosynthesize (becoming unable to tolerate food), and even grows roots in his feet that require him to be to be yanked out of the ground at one point. He decides to inform the government, only to be told that his formula would bankrupt the food industry and put millions of people out of work.

Comment: Was this a novel or a short story?

Answer (score 4):

Could it be [Going Green](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32172921-going-green) by Heather S. Ransom? I couldn't find many details beyond the blurb, but how many books are out there where a girl inserts chloroplasts under her skin to become greener?

> In the future, the color of your skin lets everyone know who you are. Those who can contribute to making the world a better place are Green, walking GMOs with plant chloroplasts in their cells who no longer need to eat. Life is good. People are happy.
>
> Well, ...some people.
> Not everyone gets to “go Green.”
>
> Calyssa Brentwood, a high school senior just finished with her cellular enhancement, is on her way to securing her place in the upper ranks of society. Until she finds herself far from the safety of Sci-City,
> ...on a farm,
> ...in the middle of a rebel insurgency.
>
> Realizing that nothing is as simple as it seems, Lyssa soon discovers that each choice brings new consequences
> ...ones that may turn deadly for those she cares about most.